# Is it possible to select an alternate USB interface using Android SDK?

Tags: android, sdk, usb

I have an USB device with interface that uses alternate settings for
its endpoints. How can I select these settings using classes in
'android.hardware.usb' package?

In native code I am using 'libusb_set_interface_alt_setting' function
from libUsb, which essentially is IOCTL. However, I wouldn't like to
use NDK for that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To enable an alternative setting for an interface is nothing more than a **Standard Device Request** according to chapter 9.4 in the [USB specification](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/usb_20_101111.zip) (usb_2.0.pdf).

So this:

```
UsbDeviceConnection.controlTransfer(UsbConstants.USB_DIR_OUT | 0x01, SET_INTERFACE, _alternate_setting_, _interface_nr_, null, 0, _timeout_);
```

should work. SET_INTERFACE (= 11 = 0x0B) is a USB specification constant. I could not find it in the android API as Java const.

Comment: Hi Alexander, thanks for the reply. I read the doc and tried to play with `controlTransfer`. Unfortunately all values of alt. settings I tried didn't work. I mentioned that `bulkTransfer` returns 1. Is there something wrong in the sequence of calls I'm using? `UsbDevice -> getInterface -> getEndpoint -> openDevice -> claimInterface -> controlTransfer -> bulkTransfer ...... -> close_connection`

Comment: What do you mean with _didn't work_? What returns the `controlTransfer` I suggested? Try the controlTransfer before claimInterface as the controlTransfer somehow changes the associated resources of the interface and our hack doesn't inform libUSB about it, however this is contrary to [the libusb recomandation](http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/group__dev.html#ga3047fea29830a56524388fd423068b53). Note: I never did that before and I can't tell what android is doing under the hood. I'm just telling you what makes sense from reading the USB specs.

Comment: By _didn't work_ I mean that data is not sent to device properly. Device receives either 0 or 1 byte from the sent package, though it's a guess - I didn't run sniffer. Regarding `controlTransfer` - it returns -1 for invalid interface ID and returns 0 for any alt.settings number with valid interface. Regarding order - if `controlTransfer` is called before `claimInterface` it returns -1 regardless of parameters.

Comment: I don't get it. If `controlTransfer` returns 0 for the mentioned request, what is the problem we are talking about? 0 means success and request data size is 0. So everything is fine. If you are not sure you really switched to the alternate setting, you may send a Get Interface request. If you are having trouble to communicate after selection of the alternate setting, that's another problem not related to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Just to close this question.

I resolved the issue by writing kernel driver for my device and using it as a char device.

As a side note, I could say that it would be nice to implement `set_interface_alt_settings` in `libusbhost` library and use it in 'android.hardware.usb' package through JNI.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well - check my solution over here:

[Android USB host DeviceConnection.setInterface prior to API Level 21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38102677/android-usb-host-deviceconnection-setinterface-prior-to-api-level-21/)

I first tried the method with a controlTransfer as suggested above, but it failed for me too. The SET_INTERFACE command was OK, and the GET_INTERFACE I read back returned the expected alternate value, so the device got the correct interface set. Even so, reads and writes to the endpoints failed :-/

I traced the libusb_set_interface_alt_setting() through libusb, usbfs and the kernel. In the kernel there is more code than simply sending a SET_INTERFACE to the USB device, for instance a comment about "9.1.1.5: reset toggles for all endpoints in the new altsetting". libusb's documentation for libusb_set_interface_alt_setting() also says:

> You should always use this function rather than formulating your own
>   SET_INTERFACE control request. This is because the underlying
>   operating system needs to know when such changes happen.

So I figured I'd better do that. Long story short: look at the code in the link above.